# How do I drop a value that exists when unable to use drop or find with the browser/editor?

Tags: stata

I can't seem to find a value anywhere in the data editor and I was unable to get 
`drop if datecode == 201209.1` to work either.

I would like to get rid of this one observation because it contains an inappropriate date. The format of the data is YYYYMM -- indicating data collection in September 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, and 2014.

```
. tabulate datecode

   DATECODE |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
     201009 |  2,113,210       20.19       20.19
     201109 |  2,130,289       20.35       40.54
     201209 |  2,110,220       20.16       60.70
   201209.1 |          1        0.00       60.70
     201309 |  2,067,262       19.75       80.46
     201409 |  2,045,706       19.54      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total | 10,466,688      100.00


. drop if datecode == 201209.1
(0 observations deleted)
```

I've included the [variable descriptive information here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afUra.png) in case that is helpful in determining the cause/solution.

I would love to understand why it's not working.

It seems that `tabulate` clearly shows the value. I don't understand why I am unable to interact with the value anywhere.

Comment: Try  `drop if round(datecode, 0.1) == 201209.1`

Comment: @Parait -- that worked perfectly! Does that mean the the function I was using was rounding them (to the nearest whole)?

Comment: This seems like a dangerous format to store this data.

Comment: `drop` is a command, not a function. (Edited out in shortening your unwieldy title.)

Answer (score 2):

Testing for exact equality with decimal fractions is more difficult than you guess because most do not have exact binary equivalents. `search precision` in Stata to find many discussions in the documentation (manuals, FAQs, Stata blog).

This dialogue shows a better method than using `round()`, namely the `float()` function. It exemplifies the most common problem in this territory when values are read into or placed in a `float` variable

```
. clear 

. set obs 1 
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen test = 201209.1 

. list 

     +----------+
     |     test |
     |----------|
  1. | 201209.1 |
     +----------+

. list if test == 201209.1

. list if test == float(201209.1)

     +----------+
     |     test |
     |----------|
  1. | 201209.1 |
     +----------+
```

`describe test` here would tell you that `test` is a `float`, which is the default numeric type.

That said, I wouldn't `drop` that observation at all. It just seems a variation on 201209. So, I would go

```
replace datecode = round(datecode, 1)
```

`round()` with integer second argument is useful. Results with `round()` with fractional second argument are often puzzling when users don't understand that Stata necessarily is working with binary approximations.

[This paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0096) has detailed discussion of handling monthly dates in formats like 201009, which isn't standard for Stata at all. In a nutshell,

```
gen year = floor(datecode/100)
gen month = mod(datecode, 100) 
gen mdate = ym(year, month) 
format mdate %tm
```

solves most problems, but read `help datetime`.

All that said (!): your question is still puzzling as your extra descriptive information shows that the variable is `double`, not `float`. With a `double` your comparison should work:

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen double datecode = 201209.1

. list if datecode == 201209.1

     +----------+
     | datecode |
     |----------|
  1. | 201209.1 |
     +----------+
```

Is something else going on? Did you import the data as `float` and then `recast double`?

Comment: Stata imported them differently when i appended the data, some were integer and some where string. I made them all match so they could be appended.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not giving me anything reproducible. The crucial detail is not what was numeric and what was string. It's why you don't get the results as in my answer when your question is saying that the variable is `double`. The last question in my answer still stands.